# Writing to Pub/Sub from Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

What I want is to write the CF result in a Pub/Sub topic. I know that I can use the API with a service account but my question is:

Is there a way to write to pub/sub directly from the CF, withouth using a custom service account?

[Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/services#using_services_with_cloud_functions) say that you can use the App Engine default service account for that, but I don't know how to put all together and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok that was easy: you only have to use the pub/sub  library and the system will load the service account automatically. Something like:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_name = 'topic/name'

def trigger(request):
    publisher.publish(topic_name, b'My first message!', spam='eggs')
```

will work without adding a SA.

Comment: Great that you found the solution! You can accept your own answer after 48 hours of posting it in your post

Comment: what does spam='eggs' do?

Comment: @pa-nguyen https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/api/client.html#google.cloud.pubsub_v1.publisher.client.Client.publish metadata